# Angular - Scope issue in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an ng-repeat that works fine when i add items to the list dynamically when i select an item. It prints the values correctly. But when i add a directive ( has an isolate scope ) it only prints the details of the first item.

.html

```
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content" ng-controller="ngDygraphCtrl">
<div class="col-sm-3 pull-right" >
        <br></br>
        <label>Add Graphs</label>
        <select ng-options="size as size.name for size in graphsx " ng-model="selected" ng-change="addGraph()"></select>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="chart1 in chartsx track by $index" >
        <br/>
         {{chart1.size}}-{{chart1.name}} {{$index}}
        <div class="row" >
            <div class="{{chart1.size}}">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                        <div class="ibox-title">
                                <h5>Line Chart {{chart1.size}}-{{chart1.name}} {{$index}}</h5>
                                <div ibox-tools></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ibox-content">
                            <div class="dynamic-chart">
                                 <ng-dygraphs style="height:350px;" data="graph.data" options="graph.options" legend="graph.legend" > </ng-dygraphs>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
```

This work fines and it prints name1, name2 etc. if i **comment out ng-dygraphs**.

I am pretty sure the isolate scope is causing some issue, but i have no clue how to address it.

.controller:

```
.controller('ngDygraphCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $modal, $interval) {
$scope.graph = {
        data: [ "X"
        ],
        options: {
           axisLineColor: "#FFFFFF",
           drawPoints: true,
           pointSize : 1,
           strokeWidth : 0.5,
           connectSeparatedPoints: true,
           axes: {
                     x: {
                         valueFormatter: Dygraph.dateString_,
                         axisLabelFormatter: Dygraph.dateAxisFormatter,
                         ticker: Dygraph.dateTicker
                     }
                 },
            colors : ["#ffff00",  "#FF3300", "#7920FF", "#ff0000", "#ff00ff"] 
        } ,
        legend: { 
        } 
    };

    $scope.chartsx = [];
    $scope.graphsx = [];

    $scope.graphsx = [{name: "name1", size: "col-lg-12"}, {name: "name2", size: "col-lg-6"}]
    // Get User state
    $scope.addGraph = function() {
        var sel = $scope.selected.name;
        for ( var ss in $scope.graphsx) {
            if ( $scope.graphsx[ss].name == sel ) {
                $scope.chartsx.push($scope.graphsx[ss]);
               // $scope.charts.push({name: sel, size: "col-sm-6"});
            }
        }        
    }
    $scope.getData = function() { $http.get('http://localhost:8080/getDygraphData?q=' + queries)
            .success(function(data) {        

            $scope.graph.data = data;

        }).error(function (data, status){
            console.log("Error status : " + status + " " + data);
        }) };
```

var promise = $interval($scope.getData, 3000);
}

Directive: Link to ng-dygraph directive( Too big to post here )

[ng-dygraph directive](https://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dygraphs/blob/master/src/angular-dygraphs.js)

Comment: DId you copy this from your code? If so, your end tag for your custom directive differs in your opening tag. direc1./ dicrec1. Not sure if that is the problem though

Comment: What is `val`? It's not related to `ng-repeat` at all. And show the code for `direct1`, otherwise we have no clue what your directive is doing that makes it ouput `"name1"`

Comment: 1. The directive is 'direc1' - Cut paste error. 2. 'val' has nothing to do with ng-repeat. It is defined inside the directive.

Comment: .directive('ngDygraphs', ['$window', '$sce', function ($window, $sce) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { // Isolate scope
                data: '=',
                options: '=',
                legend: '=?'
            },
            template: 'Lot of html code',                                               // Outer div
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) { // Other code her }

Comment: You have not indicated how `val.data` relates to the rest of the code. For all we know, the data in `val.data` is: `[{name: 'name1'},{name: 'name1'},{name: 'name1'}]`

Comment: @ksr123, what do you mean by `val` defined ***inside*** the directive? It's used clearly outside of it. Also, not sure why you showed code for `ngDygraphs` - is this `direct1`? (and you should edit your question, rather than use comments, to add more details)

Comment: Excuse me guys. First time here. I edited my original posting with all the details i have. Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As @NewDev alluded to, the most likely culprit is the declaration:

```
 <ng-dygraphs style="height:350px;" data="graph.data" options="graph.options" legend="graph.legend" > </ng-dygraphs>
```

Specifically, you're creating the directive with data that does not seem to exist which is the object **graph**. There is no variable defined on your scope for graph.

I assume you copied the code from [here](https://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dygraphs) but what you need to pass into the data, options, and legend are values defined on your scope.

Does that make sense?

Comment: There is a variable called $scope.graph with data/options/legend defined in the controller. I just did not post that code. That is first line in my code.

Comment: Do you mind updating the question with that data too then? It has something to do with that line but it's not isolated scope. An isolated scope is simple a fresh scope that's not dependent on the parent component's scope.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. The problem was with Directive and the use of 'legend', which was also defined in another directive. Changed the code to use a different scope variable instead of legend and it works fine now.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found out the problem! Do you mind answering it and marking it as answer? Just in case someone has a similar problem, they know to revisit all their code!